# Solo muestra el ultimo registro del arreglo

Tags: php, base-de-datos, oracle

El problema es que quiero mostrar el nombre y numero de Cuenta de N clientes en la BD, pero al realizar los ciclos solo me muestra el ultimo registro ingresado. El resto de los registros me da como resultado **false** al hacer un var_dump($cuenta, $cliente)

#### Código original

```
<?php 

    $mult = $_POST['numCuenta'];

    $datos = explode("\n", trim($mult));

    $cliente = []; $i = 0; $stid = []; $j = 0; $cuenta = [];

    foreach($datos as $dato){
        $nuevoArreglo[] = $dato; //Recorre cada elemento dentro del arreglo
    };

    foreach($nuevoArreglo as $row){
        $conn = new PDO('oci:dbname=192.168.1.95:1521/orcl;charset=UTF8', 'bi_src', 'bi_src');
        $stid = $conn->prepare("SELECT G300NCTL, G300CTA FROM BI_SRC.GSCF300 WHERE G300CTA = '$row' AND G300ANEX=0");
        $stid->execute();
        $result = $stid->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        
        $consulta[$i] = $result;

        foreach($consulta as $fila){
            $cuenta[] = $fila['G300CTA'];
            $cliente[] = $fila['G300NCTL'];
        };

        $i++;
    };
?>

<form action="mult.php" method="POST">
  <div class="form-row d-flex justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-6">
      <div class="form-group mt-3">
        <label for="numCuenta">Numeros de Cuenta</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" name="numCuenta" id="numCuenta"></textarea>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group mt-3">
        <input type="submit" value="Consultar" class="form-control btn btn-block btn-danger">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

---

#### Estado actual del código

```
<?php 

    $mult = $_POST['numCuenta']; #Recibo los datos del formulario mediante POST
    
    $datos = explode("\n", trim($mult)); 

    print_r($datos);

    $cliente = array();
    $cuenta = array();

    foreach($datos as $dato){
        $nuevoArreglo[] = $dato; #Recorre cada elemento dentro del arreglo
    };

    $n = count($nuevoArreglo);

    $conn = new PDO('oci:dbname=192.168.1.95:1521/orcl;charset=UTF8', 'bi_src', 'bi_src');

    foreach($nuevoArreglo as $row){
        $stid = $conn->prepare("SELECT G300NCTL, G300CTA FROM BI_SRC.GSCF300 WHERE G300CTA = '$row' AND G300ANEX=0");
        $stid->execute();
        # El while irá moviendo fila por fila     
        while($result = $stid->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
            $cuenta[] = $result['G300CTA'];
            $cliente[] = $result['G300NCTL'];
            $arrDatos[] = $result;
        }
        $stid->closeCursor();
    }
    
    var_dump($arrDatos);
  
    require_once 'index.php'; 
?>
```

Comment: No cambies totalmente la pregunta, porque si no la respuesta de Cedano queda invalida. Agrega lo que tenes ahora como te pidio el debajo de lo que tenias antes. Tambien, sacale el contenedor js.. aca no hay nada de js ;)

Comment: La voy a sacar del code snippet. Los code snippet son para código que se puede probar, dado que no es el caso, el code snippet no hace otra cosa que estorbar aquí.

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya todo bien

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PDO te devuelve un recurso con los datos, luego hay que ir moviendo fila por fila para leer los resultados. Dado que aplicas una sola vez el método `fetch` obtienes un solo dato. Por tanto, tienes que pasar el `fetch`  dentro de un bucle, así irá recorriendo el conjunto de resultados fila por fila y guardándolo en los otros arrays.

Por ejemplo:

```
$mult = $_POST['numCuenta'];
$datos = explode("\n", trim($mult));
$cliente = array();
$cuenta = array();

foreach($datos as $dato){
    $nuevoArreglo[] = $dato; //Recorre cada elemento dentro del arreglo
};


$conn = new PDO('oci:dbname=192.168.1.95:1521/orcl;charset=UTF8', 'bi_src', 'bi_src');

foreach($nuevoArreglo as $row){
    $row=(int) trim($row);
    if ( !empty(trim($row)) ){
        $sql="SELECT G300NCTL, G300CTA FROM BI_SRC.GSCF300 WHERE G300CTA = :G300CTA AND G300ANEX=0";
        $stid = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $stid->bindParam(':G300CTA', $row, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        if ( $stid->execute(){

            # El while irá moviendo fila por fila     
            while ( $result = $stid->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
                $cuenta[] = $result['G300CTA'];
                $cliente[] = $result['G300NCTL'];
                $arrDatos[] = $result; #Sólo para probar
            }
            $stid->closeCursor();

        } else {
            print_r( $conn->errorInfo() );
        }
    } else { 
        echo "valor nulo...".PHP_EOL;
    }
}

var_dump($arrDatos); # Prueba
```

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88859/discussion-on-answer-by-a-cedano-solo-muestra-el-ultimo-registro-del-arreglo).

Comment: Muchas gracias, `$row=(int) trim($row);` resolvio todo

Comment: @VíctorÁlvarez me alegro. De todos modos, considera limpiar los datos en el cliente, dado que los estás pasando por POST. Para este tipo de comunicación cliente/servidor, lo mejor es usar Ajax y limpiar los datos del lado del cliente. Saludos.